# Conjecture $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(1+x+x^2\right)}x dx\stackrel?=\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}\psi^{(1)}(\tfrac13)-\frac{4\pi^3}{27\sqrt3}-\frac23\zeta(3)$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form, polylogarithm, polygamma

I'm interested in the following definite integral:
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\!\left(1+x+x^2\right)}x\,dx.\tag1$$
The corresponding antiderivative can be evaluated with *Mathematica*, but even after simplification is [quite clumsy](http://goo.gl/ndCYA3). It matches results of numerical integration, and its correctness can potentially be verified by hand using differentiation. So, we are assured that a closed form exists for $I$, albeit complicated one.

My program for a numerical search for closed forms found a much simpler candidate:

> $$I\stackrel{\color{gray}?}=\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}\psi^{\small(1)}\!\left(\tfrac13\right)-\frac{4\pi^3}{27\sqrt3}-\frac23\zeta(3).\tag2$$

Note that the trigamma value here can be expressed in terms of the dilogarithm of complex argument (see formula $(5)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html)) or of the $2^{nd}$ order harmonic number of fractional argument:
$$\begin{align}\psi^{\small(1)}\!\left(\tfrac13\right)&=\frac{2\pi^2}3+2\sqrt3\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left[(-1)^{\small1/3}\right],\tag3\\\psi^{\small(1)}\!\left(\tfrac13\right)&=\frac{\pi^2}6+9-H^{\small(2)}_{\small1/3}.\tag4\end{align}$$
Can we prove $(2)$, preferably not going through the huge intermediate antiderivative?

---

One possible direction that I thought of is to factor the polynomial under the logarithm:
$$I=\int_0^1\Big[\ln\!\left(x+(-1)^{\small1/3}\right)+\ln\!\left(x-(-1)^{\small2/3}\right)\Big]^2x^{-1}\,dx.\tag5$$
After expanding the square brackets, *Mathematica* can find a [simpler antiderivative](http://goo.gl/0N0NJx) for it. Can we reach $(2)$ following this direction manually?

Comment: As a bonus point, we can also try to prove
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\!\left(1+x+x^2\right)}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{4\pi^2}9-\frac32 \ln^2 3+\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\ln3-\frac13\psi^{\small(1)}\!\left(\tfrac13\right). \tag{$\diamond$}$$

Comment: Bonus point is easier. Integrating by parts kills one of the logarithms; Any expression of the form $R_1(x)\ln R_2(x)$ admits an easily computable antiderivative expressed in terms of dilogarithms (factor $R_2$ and decompose $R_1$ into partial fractions).

Comment: I knew this was Vladimir before I opened the post... I'm always impressed with the formulas you come up with!

Comment: You may want to consider *Catalan's constant* $K = \rm{Cl}_2\big(\tfrac\pi2\big)$ and its cubic counterpart *Gieseking's constant* $\color{red}\kappa =\rm{Cl}_2\big(\tfrac\pi3\big)$ as having **equal** status. Hence, many integrals would have a closed-form like, $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x^2+x+1)}{x}dx =\frac{4\pi\,\color{red}\kappa}9-\frac{2\zeta(3)}3 $$ $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+x+1}dx =\frac{4\sqrt3\,\color{red}\kappa}9$$ etc. More can be found in [this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259519/list-of-integrals-or-series-for-giesekings-constant-rmcl-2-big-tfrac-pi3).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3489230/515527) and the related links from that answer.

Answer (score 11):

1. Replace $\ln(1+x+x^2)$ by $\ln(1-x^3)-\ln(1-x)$.
2. Two of the resulting integrals are easy to compute:
   $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(1-x^3\right)dx}{x}=\frac23\zeta(3),\quad \int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(1-x\right)dx}{x}=2\zeta(3).$$
3. Mathematica computes and fullsimplifies the remaining nontrivial integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)\ln\left(1-x^3\right)dx}{x}$ to a [one-line expression](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30a3ce812faf3ea3ed87) containing a sum of two trilogarithms $\operatorname{Li}_3(z_1)+\operatorname{Li}_3(z_2)$.
4. It so happens that $z_1+z_2=1$, hence thanks to [Landen's identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/17/02/03/02/0001/) the above sum is equal to $$-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{z_1}{z_1-1}\right)+\zeta\left(3\right)+\text{elementary}.$$
5. Finally, it so happens that $\frac{z_1}{z_1-1}=e^{2\pi i/3}$ and the corresponding trilogarithmic value [is known](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/03/02/02/0005/) in terms of $\zeta(3)$.

Altogether this should lead to your answer.

Comment: Thanks!
4. I would hesitate to call the term $\zeta(3)$ elementary. I believe, it's still an open question.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes, the word "elementary" is maybe not very appropriate but I have not found a better one. I meant that it does not contain polylogs.

Answer (score 2):

By some simple manipulations the integral gets reduced to calculating

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3 \frac{\log ^2(x)}{x-1} \ dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3\frac{\log ^2(x)}{ (x-1) \sqrt{4 x-3}} \ dx,$$

and both residual integrals are pretty easy to finish at this point.

Comment: i thought u became offsharing :D

Comment: @Agawa001 or *almost* offsharing once in a while. :-)